# C++ write to a socket causes the program to end

Tags: c++, sockets, g++

I'm making a socket server which has 2 threads, each running in a loop. The first looks for new connections and the second reads data from sockets which are already connected and replies to them. The problem is in the second one. 'write' function breaks the loops somehow and causes the program to finish... No errors occur... That is the problem.

The following code is a 2nd thread's function. If I don't write anything to a socket, the program runs well

```
void* SocketServer::threadSocketsRead( void* thisServer )
{
    SocketServer*               server; 
    int                         key,
                                playersNumber,
                                requestLength;
    Player*                     player;
    char                        message[256];
    string                      reply;

    server = (SocketServer*)thisServer;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        playersNumber = server->players.size();
        for ( key = 0 ; key < playersNumber ; key ++ )
        {
            player = server->players[key];  
            requestLength = read ( player->socket , (void*)&message , 255 );
            if ( requestLength < 0 )
            {
                perror ( "read" );
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                    If I uncomment the line, it will write data to
                    the socket and finish the whole program.

                    If I do no uncomment it, the programs runs in a loop further.
                */

                //int result = write ( player->socket , "reply\0" , 6 );
            };
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably writing to a dead socket and getting a `SIGPIPE` who's default action is to terminate the program. You can:

- Handle the SIGPIPE
- Pass `MSG_NOSIGNAL` to `send(2)`
- Set `SO_NOSIGPIPE` using `setsockopt` (it's not portable)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to figure out, how to fix it.